# CSS background cut

Tags: html, css

this is my code, and as you can see *body* has some background image, and *#cont* should be white. But I want my *div* elements to be transparent in a way that I can see body background image. Any CSS tricks that can do that?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(image.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#cont {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
#cont div {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Add the image.png as a link, so that we can see it.

Comment: I know, but I don't want my div elements to be white like #cont background. I want them to "cut" that white background and show body background image

Comment: so you want the cont hide the background image in body, while in the div inside cont you can see the body's background?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: I don't think it exist a **css trick** that can do that. you should go with js.

Comment: @PeroB You might be interested by the `clip-path` or `mask` property. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the snippet updated:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/1000/1000);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; /*include this*/
  background-attachment: fixed; /*include this*/
}
#cont {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
#cont div {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /*float: left; replaced by display inline-block*/
  display: inline-block; /*include this*/
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/1000/1000) center center no-repeat; /* <<< same body image*/
  background-size: cover; /*include this*/
  background-attachment: fixed; /*include this*/
}
```

Here is the full example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/copurayotu/edit?css,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background-image to your div elements and play with background-position to give the illusion of being transparent.

If you're using JavaScript you can get the x/y position of the element and dynamically adjust the css.

Comment: Yeah, that did cross my mind but it seems like too much adjusting to do. I was hoping I could solve it with CSS only

Comment: Or you can play with border. You let .cont being transparent, but you add white borders to the top and the bottom with 0 padding. Then you add left and right borders to your div.

Answer (score 0):

Check it:-

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#cont {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#cont div {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, I think you got it wrong - its the other way around

Comment: you can change  transparent using opacity increase/decrease.

Comment: you should be keeping `cont` white and the background image of `body` should be showing through the divs inside `cont`

Comment: Please check it & inform me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128086/discussion-between-razia-sultana-and-kukkuz).

Comment: Please now check it & inform me if you want to edit anything.

Comment: looks like there are still some more work to be done... `background-image` and `background-attachment` not in `body` element...  in `#cont div` too there are some adjustments to be made...